# Turbo C++ the increment is stuck with 2 in my BUS No. Please help me, can't use any compiler just turbo C++

Tags: c++, scanf, file-handling, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    clrscr();

    char Driver[40] ,From[10], To[10];
    int BUS=0;

    FILE *sfile;
    if ((sfile = fopen("c:\\bus.txt", "a+")) == NULL)
        BUS = 1;
    else
    {
        do
        {       
            fscanf(sfile,"%i %[^/]%*c %[^/]%*c %[^/]%*c", &BUS, Driver, From, To);
        }
        while (!feof(sfile));
        BUS += 1; //also tried BUS = BUS + 1; but no go//
    }
    printf("BUS No.: %04i", BUS); //here display shows up until 0002 only.//
    printf("\nDriver: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(Driver);
    printf("Route\n");
    printf("From: ");
    gets(From);
    printf("To: ");
    gets(To);
    printf("\nRecord saved!");
    fprintf(sfile,"%i %s/ %s-%s\n", BUS, Driver, From, To);
    fclose(sfile);

    getch();
    return (0);
}
```

help please how to increment the BUS No. - it stucks at 2 only. TIA
help please how to increment the BUS No. - it stucks at 2 only. TIA
 //what does %*c mean?//

Comment: You **must** check the result of scanf and take action if it fails. Stop doing `feof`. (Possibly the ancient version of Turbo C does not support `%[` either).  Don't do `fflush(stdin)`. Don't use `gets`.  Post a *Minimal* example that shows the problem, get rid of all the other crud. And post the input file that leads to the problem.

Comment: what are alternatives for gets()?

Comment: i'm using turbo c++ dos box, %[ is supported.

Answer (score 0):

You open the file for append/update, open it for reading (from the start)

```
fopen("c:\\bus.txt", "r")
```

Then BUS is filled. Incrementing afterwards was probably an experiment.

Comment: i am trying to add information everytime i run it, so i need it to be "a+"

Comment: The call `rewind()` before `fscanf`.

Comment: still doing the same thing though.

Comment: Can you call immediately after scanf: `printf("BUS: %i - %s\n", BUS, Driver);`? The loop distorts a clear view.

Comment: Yeah, it actually displays the input in the file. But it just loops twice and when I run it for the 3rd time, just a black screen.

Comment: i found the problem, its with the From and To strings. How can I now add another string?

Comment: Depends on the data, I am afraid you'll have to struggle for yourself; I would have done some things differently, missing some background info.

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(sfile,"%i %s/ %s-%s\n", BUS, Driver, From, To);
```

i just added the slash = %s/-%s/\n" BUS, Driver, From, To);
Thanks everyone!